# Android Enterprise - enable with Google Workspace EnterpriseID

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

In the [Android Enterprise documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview#customer_onboarding) it is mentioned that:

> There are two types of enterprises: Managed Google Play Accounts enterprises and Google Accounts enterprises.

This is what I need:

> Customers that use Cloud Identity or Google Workspace already have an existing enterprise ID and existing Google Accounts for users. With this type of enterprise, you need to sync with your customer's LDAP directory and retrieve Google Account information from Google using the Google Directory API.

> When setting up a device, each user must manually sign in with their existing Google Account. **The account will give them access to managed Google Play in addition to the other Google services already provided by their organization's Cloud Identity or Google Workspace plan.**

Our Workspace plans have an EnterpriseID, but we cannot get the API to list, update or use it.

Any calls to the API's result in:

**GET**: [https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/[enterpriseID/CompanyID]](https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/%5BenterpriseID/CompanyID%5D)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Caller is not authorized to manage enterprise.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

How can I connect to this / my own enterprise?

In the Google Workspace Admin I can create a token for an EMM-provider. But how can I, as my 'own' EMM provider, use this token to create an enterprise linked to Workspace?